# Stuck on declaring understanding public char in array, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, char

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

I am getting three errors
One is with my Bracket notation around declaring vowel(Invalid token)
the other two are with the assembly language and vowel existing in the context. I did some digging on the site; I feel like I am close with my declaration.
I could not find anything pinpointing the problem specifically.
Thank you

```
    namespace Yhasfeelings
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public char {vowel {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var programVowelGuess = new vowel();
        int count = 0;
        string wordEntry = (textBox1.Text).ToLower();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordEntry.Length; i++)
        { if (textBox1.Text.Contains(programVowelGuess[i]))
            { count++;
            }
        }
        var vowelCount = Convert.ToString(count);
        label1.Text = (vowelCount);
    }
}}
```

Comment: What is the err, and on which line?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public char[] vowel = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var programVowelGuess = new vowel();
        int count = 0;
        string wordEntry = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordEntry.Length; i++)
        {
            if (vowel.Contains(wordEntry[i]))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        label1.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still wrong with Uppercase vowels.

Comment: Thank you! I can see how this is a more efficient way of setting up my variables. The approach seems much smoother.

Comment: You're right Steve my bad, just edited to handle Uppercase correctly.

Comment: Thank you as well @Steve for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code to be compilable:

```
public char[] vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var programVowelGuess = vowel;
    int count = 0;
    string wordEntry = (textBox1.Text).ToLower();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordEntry.Length; i++)
    { if (programVowelGuess.Contains(wordEntry[i]))
        { count++;
        }
    }
    var vowelCount = Convert.ToString(count);
    label1.Text = vowelCount;
}
```

Comment: Index out of range with textbox.text.length > 6?

Comment: Thank you very much! I see how i declared char[] incorrectly.

Comment: @Steve Exactly... Maybe I should correct it...